# 1 Corinthians 11:18, what kind of divisions actually?

Tags: exegesis, communion, 1-corinthians, division

1 Corinthians 11:18

> In the first place, I hear that when you come together as a church,
>   there are **divisions** among you, and to some extent I believe it.

My question is already there by reading verse 18.

However, after reading the next verse, 20 to 21 :

> So then, when you come together, it is not the Lord's Supper you eat.
>   For when you are eating, **some of you go ahead with your own private
>   suppers**. As a result, one person remains hungry and another gets
>   drunk.

From the bold sentences, my guess of the divisions is something like this : 
*There are some who agree to "go ahead with their own private suppers",

 but there are also some who don't agree to "go ahead with their own private suppers". 

The group who agree, don't care to the hungry (the poor). 

The group who don't agree, care to the hungry (the poor).*

But since I realize that my guess above is only my own imagination, that's why I post this question.

Thank you.

Comment: As this site is primarily devoted to specific denominational doctrines and traditions, and does not approve of answers directly from the Bible, the better site for this question would be https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/. I'm not certain the translation you are using, but it seems to add a lot of words that aren't in the original. Hermeneutics can give a longer answer, but a short answer is that some people brought their own meals and got full while others went without, rather than sharing the meal, thus dividing rather than uniting each other.

Comment: The version is NIV, DKing. I got it from biblehub website. Thank you for your suggestion to ask in hermeneutics website. I will wait for a few days - in case there is another answer. It seems what you thought about the divisions is similar with me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Corinth, it's thought that the rich and the poor in the church were quite divided.  When they came together, it was in the same place, but, the rich who didn't work long hours would come early, and bring much food, and feast.  The poor, only after working, would come, but they would have only meagre food.  Paul is saying that this lack of sharing, this unconcern for the other members of "Christ's body"—i.e. the other members of the church, means the church is not celebrating "the Lord's Supper" but something else.  Unity among believers and care for one another, across all divides, including socioeconomic—and by extension, ethnic and gender etc., is expected if the church is the "Lord's body" and how we relate to one another in the church is very important to the Lord.  When Paul mentions a person who does "neglects the Lord's body" he's not talking about the communion elements but the relationships between church members.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is all about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). And for some tips on writing good answers here, see: [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/20394) Meanwhile, I hope you'll browse some of the other questions and answers here.

Comment: Some more support for your answer is in Acts Ch 2.

Comment: Thank you Mikeb. I choose your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, I've just read Act 2. Do you mean Act 2:44-46 ? My thought is : the verses "picturing" that there is no division there. Please CMIIW.

Comment: @karma please explain what CMIIW stands for.  I am not familiar with that acronyn/abbreviation.  I was thinking Acts 2 41-47, in terms of the community coming together and taking care of each other, and sharing. Is that where you were headed?

Comment: CMIIW = Correct me if I'm wrong, Korvin. I'm sorry as I'm ignorant, thinking that everybody will know what is CMIIW :). About Acts 2, yes that's what I get after reading those verses. The verse is "picturing" that there is no division there. They taking care of each other. It's different with the one in 1 Cor 11:18. At first I thought about the division in 1 Cor 11:18, there is a group who take care each other - there is another group who ignorant, doesn't care to each other.